# GitHub Actions Job getting skipped even the condition is provided

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I have been writing my yaml file for a .Net 4.8 web application deployment into different environments such as Dev, preprod, prod. Build is getting succeeded but dev deployment is getting skipped.

Here is my workflow:

```
name: publish 

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: gitacdevweb
  AZURE_DEVWEBAPP_NAME: GitAc-Dev
  AZURE_PREPRODWEBAPP_NAME: GitAc-PreProd
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: "./publish"
 
      
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: setup .Net
        id: build_step
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
      
      - name: restore
        run: dotnet restore ./deploynet.csproj
      
      - name: build
        run: dotnet build ./deploynet.csproj --configuration Release --no-restore 
      
      - name: publish
        run: dotnet publish ./deploynet.csproj --configuration Release --no-build --output '${{env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH}}'

  DeployDev:
      
      name: Deployment
      needs: publish
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' 
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      environment:
        name: Dev
      steps:
        - name: Deploy
          uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v2
          with:
              app-name: ${{env.AZURE_DEVWEBAPP_NAME}}
              publish-profile: ${{secrets.AZURE_DEVPUBLISH_PROFILE}}
              package: "${{env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH}}"
```

Comment: Missing [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) in deploy job.

Comment: Add `needs: [publish]` in deploy job and it should be fixed. Use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to lint your workflows to catch these syntax issues.

Comment: Thanks Azeem, sorry that i provided the previous code in my post, but I have added everything correctly even the needs still it is skipping the deploy job.

Comment: Your branch is `main` but your condition says `master`. The condition should be `if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'` or `if: github.ref_name == 'main'`.

Comment: Got it Bruh, I have changed . But it is still skipping. If I am not providing this as a job and without any specific env . but in a single job it is running or deploying succesfully.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an UPDATE section including your updated workflow, both expanded jobs, and their redacted logs.

Comment: Azeem, if you don't mind. Here is my repo link , plz have a look, https://github.com/jimmyraja000/devtest/

Comment: `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` is missing in your second job. See error in your workflow run: https://github.com/jimmyraja000/devtest/actions/runs/4762541605/workflow. But, the workflow in your question has it, copy/paste issue?

Comment: BTW, `env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH` won't be accessible to your second job as jobs run in different runners. You have an issue there too.

Comment: Bruh, check my main2.yml file in the workflow and check the log of publish 2 in the action . I changed as you say earlier but still the same.

Comment: Missing `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` in `main2.yml`.

Comment: Bruh, It is there, please check my last build in publish 2 actions.

Comment: Just checked https://github.com/jimmyraja000/devtest/actions/runs/4763445290/workflow. You're still using `master` but your branch name is `main`.

Comment: Thank you so much Azeem, got the deployment . silly things that i didn't check the code and github repo. BTW do you know how to deploy the artifact in the dev env. Have to add the upload artifacts action or any other ?

Comment: No problem. Either remove the second job, add it as a last step of the first job with an `if`; or you need to upload artifact from first job, and then download it before deploying in the second job.

Answer (score 0):

In your workflow, the branch `master` is being used whereas the branch name in your repo is `main`. You need to replace `master` with `main`.

Apart from that, the built path i.e. `AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH` is only available in the first job as jobs are run in different runners.

Either remove the second job, add it as a last step of the first job with an `if`; or upload the build built artifact from first job, and then download it before deploying in the second job.